# Sami tale where the fox is left as sole speaker of human language

Tags: sami

Does anyone know the Sami tale where all the animals gather inside a mountain and decide they won't be speaking the same language as humans from now on? If I remember correctly, they agree that one animal will remain able to communicate with humans, and it is the fox. I heard this tale in Lapland and would love to have a full version of it.

Comment: Regret I have no knowledge of this, but it sounds an interesting idea, so I hope someone can answer it.